# Share a object between Main and Child window as a means of passing data back and forth (C#)

Tags: c#, parent-child

This problem has three files:

- `Options.cs` (A datastore for option values)
- `MainWindow.cs` (The main window for the program, its appearnce is modified based on the options inside the Options datastore - once that class is decalred as a object)
- `OptionsWindow.cs` (The child window where the user sets the option value, this window then saves the changes into the `Options` datastore when the user presses a button inside the window)

What I want to do is share data between a main window form and child window form in C#.
my main window is called `MainWindow` and child window `OptionsWindow`.

I have a data store called `Options`. This is a object that stores various user options. (some are type `int` and `bool`) these options are used by `MainWindow` for appearance purposes.

So the user makes changes in the `OptionsWindow` and these variables changes get saved in the `userOptions` object of type `Options` that is declared inside the `OptionsWindow`.

I did this because I need a easy and simple way to move set data in a childwindow, save that data to a object and then use that data in the `MainWindow`

Why did I not declare the `userOptions` object inside the `MainWindow`? Because you can't access any data declared in `MainWindow` unless I make the object `public` which everyone says never ever do. So I have tried making the `userOptions` object inside the `OptionsWindow` and exposing the varaibles (data) through properties.

This works. I can access and set properties from both `OptionsWindow` and `MainWindow`.

Whats the problem? Well the `optionsWindow.Show();` can only be used once, after that C# will not let it ever work again, so for some reason its once use only. Also it seems the object `userOptions` is being destroyed once the form closes.

`MainWindow.cs`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        OptionsWindow optionsWindow = new OptionsWindow();
```

`optionsWindow` then declares an object `userOptions` of type `Options`. This is the datastore. The rest of the `optionsWindow` is getting user data and adding this data to the options datastore

```
public partial class OptionsWindow : Form
    {
        Options userOptions = new Options();

        public bool AllowToolTip
        {
            get { return userOptions.AllowToolTips; }
            set { userOptions.AllowToolTips = value; }
        }
```

I call the `optionsWindow` like this: (note this only works once because of exceptions errors, apparently C# can't reuse child objects. This is really confusing me)

```
private void optionsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                optionsWindow.Show();// this stops working after first call
            }
            catch { };

        }
```

I have been working on this code for about 4 hours trying everything.

All I want is to have a data store of user options of various types and use a options window to set the options and a main window to read the options.

That is all I want to do.

Set variables into a shared datastore inside a child window and access that datastore in the main window.

The data store is a object.

Is this fixable? Or is there a better way to get data from a child-window that can be accessed by both the child-window and the main-window.

EDIT: I ended up making the datastore public because the code was becoming too convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding Options property to your OptionsWindow form.

```
public partial class OptionsWindow : Form
{
    public Options { get; set; }

    public bool AllowToolTip
    {
        get { return Options.AllowToolTips; }
        set { Options.AllowToolTips = value; }
    }
}
```

in your MainWindow you simply set the options and read it when done.

```
private void optionsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        optionsWindow.Options = myOptions;
        optionsWindow.ShowDialog();
        myOptions = optionsWindow.Options;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make `Options` a seperate (static) configuration or datastore class. Such you can use it everywhere. Or you create it from `MainWindow` and provide it via constructor or another method to the `OptionWindow`.

Regarding `Show()` in `OptionWindow` - you could subscribe to its `Closing` event (from inside itself) and set it to cancel (`FormClosingEventArgs`) and then Hide() this window. This way `OptionWindow` is not destroyed and can be shown anytime again. Also, userOptions will not be destroyed. There's one additional point though: If you want to end your program you must really close the window (instead of hiding it). Otherwise the program will stay running.